# EF 6 DataBase First Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When using EF6 Database First and trying to execute a stored procedure the auto-generated context adds the required method but sets the return type as ObjectResult. For example the following definition:

```
public virtual ObjectResult<USP_GetItemDetails_Result> USP_GetItemDetails(int? itemNbr, int? siteNbr)
```

Has the return type of:

```
return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<USP_GetItemDetails_Result>("USP_GetItemDetails", itemNbr, siteNbr);
```

Is there anyway to materialize this result as just the concrete class rather than having to send the result as ObjectResult? The next layer in my stack is not aware of Entity Framework.

Comment: Also if its relevant the return type of the stored procedure is a Complex Type that does not match any of the DB entities (it's an amalgamation of some local info and data from a linked server)

Comment: why don't mapping the result yourself into a new class?

Comment: I could do that but then I would be mapping again later when I return the results as a dto through web API.

Comment: You could use Automapper http://automapper.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out ObjectResult under the hood is an IEnumerable. A simple toList means I can return an IEnumerable to the next layer.